# Datetime is wrong in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime, dst

I am in Eastern Standard Time (EST). Daylight savings time started 2 weeks ago, where clocks were turned forward 1 hour (so 5PM became 6PM). I have `USE_TZ = True`. TIME_ZONE is set to “EST”.

In my app, I have a form that submits a date, like 2AM. That date, still 2AM, gets saved in a model as a DateTime field: `event.start = date`. I have a view that renders the date, and the page shows 2AM correctly.

The problem: `event.start` evaluates to 3AM (EST) / 8AM (UTC), 1 hour later that what it's supposed to be! The input was 2AM, it even renders 2AM in templates, but for some reason internally `event.start` is 8AM (UTC) / 3AM (EST).

But for some reason `django.utils.timezone.now()` gives me the correct time 2AM, instead of 3AM. My OS system time also gives the correct time, 2AM. I want to schedule a job for 2AM, but it ends up getting scheduled for 3AM instead because `event.start` is set to 3AM for some reason!

I want to keep times in UTC. How do I deal with this?

Comment: Providing more information would be helpful - what exact type is the column, do you have TIME_ZONE set to your correct location?

Comment: @Jindra ok I added that information. Hope it helps solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Eastern Standard Time` doesn't have daylight saving time, it is hard offset from UTC. When there are daylight savings places switch from `Eastern Standard Time` to `Eastern Daylight Time`(EDT).

More information: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/est

Using Olson identifier is usually better solution. They are the identifiers used in IANA timezone database. They are location based, so when the location changes TimeZone (including daylight savings) everything still works.

Example of a place that changes EST <-> EDT:

```
America/New_York
```

Try changing `TIME_ZONE` from `EST` to Olson identifier for your desired location.

Comment: So will this still break for users in other timezones? Is there a way to automatically get users’ Olson identifiers and attach them to the date when they submit a form, or does Django already do this?

Comment: Depends on what do you mean as "break". It would behave as if everyone was in ```America/New_York```. If you want per user settings, you need to pass timezone info with each and every datetime object all the way from user client to the database. Timezones are complex things and out of scope of SO answer. I suggest reading up on the topic.  Some good information can be found on this blog: https://codeofmatt.com/tag/time-zone/.