# Django not accounting for Daylight Savings Time

Tags: python, django

The issue is pretty simple, but I can't for the life of me find any information on it.  Based on my internet searches, it seems like this should be a non-issue; Django should be doing this automatically.

My issue is that ever since DST began, Django has been converting times to displays on the webpages 1 hour before the times should be.  I say converting to because I've enabled "USE_TZ" in settings, so the times are being saved to the database in UTC, but the times are incorrectly converted to EST as they are one hour behind.

What could be causing this?

Here's an example:

This is the model.

```py
class Chat(models.Model):
    chat_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    chat_user = models.ForeignKey(UserExt, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    chat_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    chat_type = models.CharField(default="chat", blank=False, null=False, max_length=20)
    chat_message = models.TextField()
```

This is an example of a model being saved to the database

```py
new_chat = ClubChat()
new_chat.chat_user = self.user
new_chat.chat_message = message
new_chat.chat_destination = self.club
new_chat.save()
```

And this is an example of a webpage that displays the date/time

```html
<tr {% if chat.chat_type == 'info' %} class="joinleavemessage"{% endif %}>
            <td>
                {% if chat.chat_user %}<p>{{ chat.chat_user }}</p>{% endif %}
                <p>{{ chat.chat_time|date:'m/d/Y h:i A' }}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>{{ chat.chat_message }}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

This issue is site-wide, so this isn't the only example.

Comment: What's your timezone in settings?

Comment: What is `TIME_ZONE` in settings.py?

Comment: It's set to 'EST'

Comment: Show us how these times are generated, saved to the database, retrieved from the database, and displayed on the page.

Comment: If it's set to EST, then django converting the times to EST isn't incorrect, it's just doing what you've set it to. If you want your time in UTC, set the `TIME_ZONE` to UTC

Comment: But I want my time in Eastern Standard Time.  I'm not in the UTC timezone.  My issue is that Django isn't taking into account DST, not that my time is in the wrong timezone.

Comment: What database engine is Django using?  Is the database itself set to respect dst?

Comment: My django is using an sqlite3 database, and I don't know how to set it to respect DST.  I've never heard of that—It's something I assumed Django did automatically.  I recall seeing something on the django website that inferred that.

Comment: I would try setting to `TIME_ZONE='America/New_York'` "EST" and "EDT" are different, and it's possible a package or some code isn't automatically assuming daylight savings. Using the TZ location should help target the correct timezone.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60863724/datetime-is-wrong-in-django - using `EST` will indeed ignore daylight savings, because `EST` is defined as `UTC-5` - it's not going to change based on time of year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `TIME_ZONE='America/New_York'` (or whatever appropriate locale).

"EST" (UTC−05:00) and "EDT" (UTC−04:00) are different specific time offsets, and don't change with daylight savings, you need to use a location based timezone which will take into account daylight savings seasonal change.

Comment: Ben answering Ben. Awesome :)

Comment: You're my savior.  You've helped me more than you know.  Thank you so much.